# px4 Drone does not follow Mavsdk control

Tags: ros, tracking, yolo

I’m writing code to publish Gotrun’s cv2 screen to Ros Detection in real time, then subscribe to that image and use mavsdk to issue commands to control the drone based on the size and position of the bounding box.

```
await self.drone.offboard.set_velocity_body(
                VelocityBodyYawspeed(p, r, t, y))
```

When I give this control command, the drone turns on and off again. I’m wondering why?

```
import asyncio
from mavsdk import System
from std_msgs.msg import String
from mavsdk.offboard import (VelocityBodyYawspeed,VelocityNedYaw, PositionNedYaw, OffboardError)
import rospy

class Navigation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.detection_info = ""
        self.centerx = 240
        self.centery = 220
        self.height = 100
        self.tolx = 20
        self.toly = 20
        self.tolh = 20
        self.drone = System()

    def detection_cb(self, msg):
        self.detection_info = msg.data

    async def setup_and_takeoff(self):
        await self.drone.connect(system_address="udp://:14540")

        print("Waiting for drone to connect...")
        async for state in self.drone.core.connection_state():
            if state.is_connected:
                print(f"-- Connected to drone!")
                break

        print("Waiting for drone to have a global position estimate...")
        async for health in self.drone.telemetry.health():
            if health.is_global_position_ok and health.is_home_position_ok:
                print("-- Global position estimate OK")
                break

        print("-- Arming")
        await self.drone.action.arm()

        print("-- Setting initial setpoint")
        await self.drone.offboard.set_velocity_body(
            VelocityBodyYawspeed(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

        print("-- Starting offboard")
        try:
            await self.drone.offboard.start()
        except OffboardError as error:
            print(f"Starting offboard mode failed with error code: \
                {error._result.result}")
            print("-- Disarming")
            await self.drone.action.disarm()

        await self.control_loop()
        
    async def control_loop(self):

        while True :
            cx, cy, h = self.detection_info.split()
            cx = int(float(cx))
            cy = int(float(cy))
            h = int(float(h))

            p,r,t,y = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0  

            if abs(cx - self.centerx) > self.tolx:  
                if cx - self.centerx <= 0:
                    r = 1.0 

                else: 
                    r = -1.0  


            if abs(cy - self.centery) > self.toly: 
                if cy - self.centery > 0:
                    t = -5.0 

                else: 
                    t = 5.0 


            if abs(h - self.height) > self.tolh: 
                if h - self.height > 0:
                    p = -1.0 

                else : 
                    p = 1.0

            await self.drone.offboard.set_velocity_body(
                VelocityBodyYawspeed(p, r, t, y))

            await asyncio.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node("detection", anonymous=False)
    navigation = Navigation()
    detection_sub = rospy.Subscriber("detection_info", String, callback=navigation.detection_cb)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(navigation.setup_and_takeoff())
```

I expected to subscribe to the image information of the goturn tracker and then track the relative object through that information, but the drone is not moving.